# Unicode in C++ Not Displaying in Mac Terminal

Tags: c++, variables, internationalization, chinese-locale

`Terminal > Profiles > Advanced > Text encoding` is set as `Unicode (UTF-8)`.

`Terminal > Profiles > Advanced > Set locale environment variables on startup` is checked.

`Terminal > Profiles > Advanced > Unicode East Asian Ambiguous characters are wide` is checked (I've tried it unchecked, as well -- both give the same results).

The font selected in the Terminal profile is compatible with Chinese characters -- I've checked it.

I checked `locale` through the Terminal itself, and it gives the following:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

-- I'm not sure if this is the problem, as it says `en_US` but also says `UTF8`, which is the encoding of the characters I'm entering.

To test all this, I've used the following code:

```
char dao [4] = "\u9053";
std::wcout << "Character: " << dao << std::endl;

wchar_t wdao[] = L"道";
std::wcout << "Character 2: " << wdao << std::endl;
```

At first, the characters came up as question marks, but now they don't show up at all. If I put all of these lines into a program, all that shows up is `Character:` -- it never makes it to the second line, it doesn't show the Chinese character, and no error is given.

I've tried `setlocale();` but it doesn't help.

I've also made sure that the source file for the C++ code is set as `Unicode UTF-8`.

Any ideas? Is there something I'm missing, here?

UPDATE: I can get the characters to display in the terminal through this method:

```
char dao [4] = "道";
std::cout << "Character: " << dao << std::endl;

char dao2 [4] = "\u9053";
std::cout << "Character: " << dao2 << std::endl;
```

That said, I could never get it to work with `wchar_t` instead of `char[]`. I suppose this is good enough, as it functions, however, if someone knows what the issue was with using `wchar_t`, I'd appreciate knowing that for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

There  is no << operator that outputs a narrow string to a wostream (such as wcout).

That's what you're doing in the first case, you declare

```
char dao [4] = "\u9053";
```

And then try to output it to std::wcout

Comment: Thank you, but I tried wide characters with `wcout` and it didn't work, either. For some reason, I couldn't get a Chinese character to be contained within a wide character and then print it through `wcout` -- that was my original intention because I wanted to be able to deal with the characters as singular things rather than character arrays. If you have any ideas about why that may be, please do let me know. Working with Chinese characters has been a tad complex, and it's made it hard to tell what exactly is going wrong.